# How to convert datetime format in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert the DateTime format using c#. This is my code

```
string date = "Thu May 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)";
var s = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

But this code not working the exception is **'System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'**

Comment: `var s = DateTime.ParseExact(date.Substring(0, date.IndexOf("(")).Trim().Replace("GMT", ""),"ddd MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` - If it doesn't fit, make it fit. https://dotnetfiddle.net/1mdkxg

Comment: ^^ In future, insist on ISO Date format in interface negotiation meetings.

Answer (score 2):

The format you provide must match with the format used in the string. Hence the name `ParseExact`. After playing around a bit I was able to match these:

```cs
string date = "Thu May 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700"
var s = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz", null);
```

You may need to manually truncate the (Pacific Daylight Time) or include it in the format as a literal (like I did with GMT here).

For more information you can work with [DateTime format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Note that you can also use single quotes instead of escaping double quotes to make it read a little better: `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz", null);`

Answer (score 0):

Your format string means that the date value must be something like that:

```
string date = "20-05-2021 12:00:00";
var s = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Try to use an other date value or change the date format string.

You can find a lot of good examples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

Comment: But I am getting this format Thu May 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) only.